# How to create formula object from strings for "rlm"

Tags: r, lm

I need to create a formula from strings, now standard way to do this is

```
f <- paste(var1, var2, sep="~")
lm(f, data=<some data.frame> ...)
```

But this surprisingly fails for "rlm" which is also supposed to accept formula //present in MASS package

```
rlm(formula, data, weights, ..., subset, na.action,
    method = c("M", "MM", "model.frame"),
    wt.method = c("inv.var", "case"),
    model = TRUE, x.ret = TRUE, y.ret = FALSE, contrasts = NULL)
```

This is the error i am getting

```
Na/NaN/Inf in foreign function call
```

PS: this works fine if i just hard-code the formula instead of using f

Comment: Are you looking for `as.formula`?

Comment: `rlm` does accept `formula` objects, but not 'character' objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `as.formula` to make `f` a forumla object:

```
f <- as.formula(paste("stack.loss",".",sep="~"))
rlm(f, stackloss, psi = psi.bisquare)
Call:
rlm(formula = f, data = stackloss, psi = psi.bisquare)
Converged in 11 iterations

Coefficients:
(Intercept)    Air.Flow  Water.Temp  Acid.Conc. 
-42.2852537   0.9275471   0.6507322  -0.1123310 

Degrees of freedom: 21 total; 17 residual
Scale estimate: 2.28
```